# PHP array object cast integer with array_map or array_walk

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to write a tiny function to cast the `status` and `total` values in integer  on my multidimentional array , i guess i need t o use array_map or array_walk ? :

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'status' => '0',
    'total' => '6',
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'status' => '1',
    'total' => '37',
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    'status' => '2',
    'total' => '8',
  ),
)
```

to get this result

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'status' => 0,
    'total' => 6,
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'status' => 1,
    'total' => 37,
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    'status' => 2,
    'total' => 8,
  ),
)
```

Comment: You guess well.

Comment: Next time include your attempt, or edit and add your attempt, even if it's a catastrophe.  Otherwise you'll likely get negative feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the values of each sub array through intval:

```
<?php
$data =
[
    [
        'status' => '1',
        'total'  => '2',
    ],
    [
        'status' => '3',
        'total'  => '4'
    ],
];

$result = array_map(fn($v)=>array_map('intval', $v), $data);

var_dump($result);
```

Output:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["status"]=>
    int(1)
    ["total"]=>
    int(2)
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    ["status"]=>
    int(3)
    ["total"]=>
    int(4)
  }
}
```

Or just transform the leaves in-place:

```
array_walk_recursive($data, function(&$v) { $v = (int) $v; });
```

And a simple foreach with type juggling:

```
foreach($data as &$v) {
    $v['status']+=0;
    $v['total'] +=0;
}
unset($v);
```

Comment: Thank you for those both approach very nice , i learned a lot with this

Comment: A foreach isn't that much longer (one-liner): `foreach($data as&$a)foreach($a as&$v)$v=(int)$v;unset($v,$a);` If you don't care about the dangling references, it can be reduced further.

Comment: Golfed: `foreach($data as&$a)foreach($a as&$v)$v+=0;`

Comment: wondering if a basic `foreach()` isn't (much) faster...

Comment: The argument for foreach is that it's explicit, and is probably less to learn/remember.  This version satisfies Php 4.3 to 8: https://3v4l.org/0tQCv